# sqlalchemy engine trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of provided IP

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, pymysql

I'm writing here because I can't find any other information on this specific bug.

Whenever I try to connect to my remote DB using

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{creds.user}:{creds.dbpassword}@{creds.host}:{creds.port}/{creds.database}')
```

It tells me:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I explicitly have creds.host set to the IP of the sever as well as I get the same error when I put it directly into the engine. This works on the remote machine under root but does not work for me and it works for a partner who runs the exact same code. Some of the links I found was suggesting to change the bind-address in the mysql config. I uninstalled my local mariadb/mysql server and went and found the config file with bind-address and uncommented it so it was bind-address=0.0.0.0 after a reboot its still not working so I have to think that it is my machine that is not letting me connect to the server.

New info: My partner can no-longer connect through pymysql. I can still connect through datagrip and mysql workbench. The port is open and mysql is listening on port 3306. I have appropriate permissions as I know this because I can connect through datagrip and mysql workbench. I'm thinking this is an us problem and not a server problem but I just don't know why because nothing has changed before the issue started.

Comment: What does the f-string render to?

Comment: ```host = "162.theremoteserverip", port = "3306", user = "myusername", dbpassword = "mypassword", database = "kotdtest"``` Won't let me format it better than this. Sorry

Comment: Shouldn't the result start with `mysql+pymysql://`?

Comment: Ah yes sorry I see what you mean now. ```'mysql+pymysql://myusername:mydatabasepassword@190.0.0.0:3306/database'```